# Post on cUrl not working with Postman to test API

Tags: php, laravel-5, oauth-2.0

I'm using Postman to test an API, with the following parameters:

URL: http://192.168.0.10:8000/user (it's working)
Method: post

Headers:
Accept: application/json
Authorization : (here comes the token, which is valid)
login: username that's trying to log into software

Now, get on that URL is fine, but POST return's:

> { "message": "", "exception": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException", "file":

And a lot of other lines.

On my routes, we have:
Route::post('agile', 'AgileController@store');

Anyone have a tip?

Answer (score 1):

It can be CSRF token if you are sure that your routes are correct. Check https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf.

Comment: Ok, but how can I send csrf through curl? And is inside a while (importing users from one software to another).

Comment: Wait I found the solution, I will post.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was simply shutdown server and restart. A drastic solution but was running in local server, so not big deal.